# Display image on radio select and add price

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to select club and display image and return price using radio buttons.
Im stuck because I cannot get the pictures to display. any ideas what could i add?

```
            <label>Select  Club:</label><br>
            <UL>
                <label class="radiolabel"><input type="radio" name="SelectedJersy" value="MUFC" onclick="displayJersy()"> MUFC-(15&#8364;)</label><br>
                <label class="radiolabel"><input type="radio" name="SelectedJersy" value="MCFC" onclick="displayJersy()"> MCFC-(20&#8364;)</label><br>
            </UL>
            <div id='jersy'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var img_Jersy = new Array();
img_Jersy["MUFC"]= "<img src='data/images/MUFC.png'>";
img_Jersy["MCFC"]= "<img src='data/images/MCFC.png'>";

var jersy_prices = new Array();
jersy_prices["MUFC"]=15;
jersy_prices["MCFC"]=10;

function displayJersy()
{  
   var jersyPrice=0;
   var theForm = document.forms["tshirtform"];
   var selectJersy = theForm.elements["SelectedJersy"];
   for(var i = 0; i < selectJersy.length; i++)
       {
       //if the radio button is checked
       if(selectJersy[i].checked)
       {
       jersyPrice = jersy_prices[selectJersy[i].value];
        //imgJersy = img_Jersy[selectJesry[i].value];
       imgJersy = img_Jersy[selectJesry[i].value];
       document.getElementById("jersy").innerHTML =imgJersy;
       document.getElementById('jersy').style.visibility="visible";
       break;
    }
 return jersyPrice;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple issues. You forgot a closing curly brace in your for loop.

There's a typo here:

```
imgJersy = img_Jersy[**selectJesry**[i].value];
```

Anyway, here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/z92togqd/2/